# Centre icon and text vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a block of links:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="icon26 icon1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="icon26 icon2">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Each link has an accompanying icon. What I'm trying to achieve is 2 things:
1) To centre both the image and the text within the LI tag
2) To block the A tag so it fills the LI tag

Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I can achieve 1 or 2 but not both at the same time - any ideas?

At present i'm using a existing sprite solution for the link - this may not be ideal, but it can be changed if a solution is found. Here's the CSS:

```
.icon26:before
{
    background:url(/assets/images/sprite26.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:2.6rem;
    width:2.6rem;
}

.icon1:before
{
    background-position:-32px -2px;
}
```

Here's the remaining CSS for the UL structure:

```
#nav ul
{
    width:100%;
}

#nav ul li
{
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;
}

#nav a
{
    display:block;
    line-height:4.6rem;
}

#nav a:before
{
    margin:1rem 0.5rem 1rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? It works http://jsfiddle.net/fj0nLnz4/as expected (I've only added there some colors).

Comment: @panther the question is clear: they are trying to center the icon and text horizontally and vertically inside each link.

Comment: @panther - strange, that's not what I see - I need to investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly possible. Remove the `float`, and use a combination of `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` instead.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7k62m8z/).

Here's the relevant code:

```
.icon26:before {
    background: url(/assets/images/sprite26.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block; /* <-- instead of float: left */
    vertical-align: middle; /* <-- add to vertically center inline blocks */
    height: 2.6rem;
    width: 2.6rem;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center; /* <-- add this to horizontally center inline items */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `<A>` `position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;`. And make icon and link center align same as you did. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell;` property to center align vertically & set `width: 1%` for full width (justified) menu items.

```
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.nav > li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1%;
}
.nav > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/ramzXG

Warning: This method is buggy in Safari 8.0